# Send data in tabhost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tabhost

I have 3 activities: main_tabhost, tab1, tab2
and a variable int t;

when i click tab1, increase t. Then i click tab2: how can I get value of t in tab 2?
give me some ideas or source code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a "sticky" broadcast `Intent` from tab1.

In the tab1 `Activity` when `t` is changed...

```
Intent i = new Intent("myapp.action.DO_SOMETHING");
i.putExtra("t_value", t);
sendStickyBroadcast(i);
```

In the tab2 `Activity` you need to create an inner `BroadcastReceiver`...

```
public class MyActivity2 extends Activity {

    ...

    private class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the `onResume()` method of the tab2 `Activity` register the receiver and get the "sticky" `Intent`...

```
int t;
Intent i = registerReceiver(new MyReceiver(), new IntentFilter("myapp.action.DO_SOMETHING"));
if (i != null)
    t = i.getIntExtra("t_value", 0);
// Do something with `t`
```

NOTE: You will need to specify the `android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY` permission in your manifest file.

Answer (score -1):

define t as a public static variable .

Comment: Never define anything as `public static` in an `Activity` and expect to be able to access it from any other application component.